# Como alinhar o texto na frente de outro elemento?

Tags: css

Consegui arredondar as bordas da div só não estou conseguindo alinhar o texto na frente da div.

Meu código está assim:

```css
.boxEtapas {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.etapas {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.etapas ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.etapas ul,
li {
  margin: 1px;
}

.redondo {
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  line-height: 1.0;
}

.redondoativo {
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #337ab7;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.0;
}

.textoEtapas {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6 boxEtapas" align="center">
  <div class="etapas">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="redondoativo">
          <br>1</div>
        <div class="textoEtapas">Informações Cadastrais</div>
      </li>
      <li>|</li>
      <li>
        <div class="redondo">
          <br>2</div>
        <div class="textoEtapas">Selecionar Assinatura</div>
      </li>
      <li>|</li>
      <li>
        <div class="redondo">
          <br>3</div>
        <div class="textoEtapas">Forma de Pagamento</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Coloca o código CSS que você fez aí para continuarmos nele.

Comment: Pronto coloquei.

Comment: Já tentou colocar `float: left;` nas classes  `.redondoativo` e `.redondo`?

Comment: É só tirar os `<br>` antes do número. Depois coloca `line-height: 50px` no lugar de **1.0**

Comment: Ja coloquei o floa left mais fica mais bagunçado BrunoRomualdo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
.boxEtapas {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.etapas {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.etapas ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.etapas ul,
li {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  line-height: 50px;
}
.redondo {
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  line-height: 50px;
  float: left;
}
.redondoativo {
  background-color: #337ab7;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.textoEtapas {
  float: left;
  text-indent: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6 boxEtapas" align="center">
  <div class="etapas">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="redondo redondoativo">1</div>
        <div class="textoEtapas">Informações Cadastrais</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="redondo">2</div>
        <div class="textoEtapas">Selecionar Assinatura</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="redondo">3</div>
        <div class="textoEtapas">Forma de Pagamento</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigada Gumball ficou melhor alinhado os numeros dentro da div mas não resolveu o problema ;) o texto ainda fica abaixo como na imagem!

Comment: Mas qual o problema ? Você disse **não estou conseguindo alinhar o texto na frente da <div>**... O que isso realmente significa ?

Comment: colocar o texto que esta dentro da class textoEtapas na frente da "bolinha" rs

Comment: Produção, de novo -1.

Comment: A resposta está ok, faltou só um `text-align: center` nessa regra `.redondo` pro texto ficar no meio da bolinha. +1

Answer (score 7):

A questão do alinhamento, pode ter um único elemento (um parágrafo, por exemplo) e utilizar pseudo elementos para criar aquelas bolinhas com o número na frente:

```css
.steps p {
  counter-increment: items /* contador de steps */
}

.steps p::before {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  content: counter(items);
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  margin-right: 15%; /* distancia do circulo p/ o texto */
  pointer-events: none
}

.steps p.selected::before {
  border-color: #3D8EB9;
  background: #3D8EB9;
  color: #fff
}
```

```html
<div class='steps'>
  <p class='selected'>Informações Cadastrais</p>
  <p>Selecionar Assinatura</p>
  <p>Forma de Pagamento</p>
</div>
```

Se quiser as bolinhas do lado direito, basta alterar a regra para `.steps p::after` e alterar o `margin-right` para `margin-left`.

Comment: Embora tenha a tag ASP, isso foi meio que respondido [nessa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77677/4808).

Answer (score 4):

No seu `css` adicione um `height` aos seus `li` assim:

```
.etapas ul li{
    height:30px;
}
```

E nas classes `.redondo` e `.redondoativo` coloque um `float:left`.
Para finalizar deixe sua classe `.textoEtapas` assim:

```
.textoEtapas{
    height:30px;
    line-height:50px;
    float: left;
}
```

Dê uma olhada nesse exemplo do que fiz no [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GNyVEY).