# Como deixar o texto alinhado com a imagem

Tags: html, css

Estou criando um portfólio pra mim e estou tentando deixar o texto reto como nesse site https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-agency/# (na área about) se vocês perceberem o texto fica retinho nos primeiros parágrafos parece que foi feito com régua, e os do meu site estão quebrando linhas esta tipo assim:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit 
  amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Integer dolor lorem,      
  eudapibus. Mauris eget laoreet 
augue, quis sodales dolor.
```

```css
.tudo {
  width: 30%;
  background-color:#009;        
}
.tudo img {
  float: left;
}
.tudo p {
  padding-left: 100px;    
}
```

```html
<div class="tudo">
  <img src="http://multnix.com/stack/tags.png">
  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer dolor lorem,
    efficitur sed gravida sed, congue id magna. Vestibulum tincidunt eu sapien 
    eu dapibus. Mauris eget laoreet augue, quis sodales dolor.         
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Coloca o código.

Comment: calma ae que deu ruim vou postar jfiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ppgcdL4p/

Comment: Não precisa, Ctrl + K você formata o código ou clicando no { } na edição.

Comment: **Relacionada**: [Como alinhar o texto na frente de outro elemento?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/169300/4808)

Answer (score 0):

Entao pessoal e o seguinte uma coisa tao simples de ser resolvida e o idiota aqui usando bootstrap acabou me atrapalhando mais que ajudando e eu tinha esquecido do poderoso text-align:left  no paragrafo o my god, deixa o topico aberto ae pq nos outros topicos nenhum citou o text-align:left